# GWT DataGrid Item selection centered KeyboardSelectionPolicy

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I'm having a DataGrid which is resizeable (ResizeLayout). My main problem is when I select a certain column it's correctly selected but it's put in the middle of of the DataField. Meaning I have 11 shown items (but there a more within the grid), I click (select) the 10 entry, the centered within the shown DataGrid (6 item, then the selected on, another 6 item.

I'm using a CellPreviewHandler to select my object:

```
dataGrid.addCellPreviewHandler(new CellPreviewEvent.Handler<GWTUser>() {

    @Override
    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<GWTUser> event) {
        if("click".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
            dataGrid.setKeyboardSelectedRow(dataGrid.getKeyboardSelectedRow(), true);
            dataGrid.setFocus(false);
            presenter.selectedUser(event.getValue().getId());

        }
    }
});
```

When I change `dataGrid.setKeyboardSelectedRow(dataGrid.getKeyboardSelectedRow(), true);` to 
`dataGrid.setKeyboardSelectedRow(dataGrid.getKeyboardSelectedRow(), false);` it always jumps to the top of the list. 
I basically want to select somthing from my DataGrid and nothing should happen UI wise.

thanks for any help.

**update:**

I think I found the key for the problem. it's the `KeyboardSelectionPolicy`, but when I disable it my datagrid refreshes and goes up to the top of the list. And I basically just want to click on my column get the id from my object and no reloading/refreshing or focus or what ever. Can I custom my Policy somehow?

Comment: Remove these two lines: `dataGrid.setKeyboardSelectedRow` and `dataGrid.setFocus(false)`. I don't know if it solves your problem, but you don't need these lines anyway.

Comment: yeah those lines where useless. I think I kinda found the problem it's the `KeyboardSelectionPolicy` but when I disable it i always refreshes the list and shows goes up to the top. Hopefully there is a policy which I can use.